# Stuck thread after throwing unhandled exception

Tags: java, exception

I have an application that runs headless and needs to be able to notify administrators of problems. I built an email notification framework for it to use, and basically if an exception is thrown and caught, depending on the area in code and the criticality of the exception, it may be passed into the alert notification framework which triggers an email to go out to the listed admins with the stack trace and other debug info.

This works, pretty well.

Before deploying, I was putting it through it's paces. One of my tests is to throw an unhandled exception from a random spot in code - simulating a potentially serious runtime problem where exceptions are being thrown that we did not expect.

For example, here is a method I inserted the test unhandled exception:

```
/**
 * Closes connection.
 */
public void closeConnection() {
    if (true)
    throw new NullPointerException("Test unexpected exception NPE");
    LOG.info("Closing SFTP connection");
    getSftpChannel().exit();
    getSession().disconnect();
    LOG.debug("SFTP Connection closed");

}
```

The code runs, and when it gets to this unhandled exception, the program hardlocks (because exception is thrown and the sftp connection thread is never closed, so it holds the jvm open until the connection timeout).

I had thought it would crash the JVM, or pass it up to it's caller which eventually would bubble up to the alert system.

In this scenario, I had assumed this NPE would throw out of this exception, isn't handled by it's caller or the caller's caller, etc, so it should bubble to the main() and then crash the JVM since even main does not catch `Exception` or NPE's.

`Question`: What is going on here and how can I ensure a scenario like this won't hang in production? Do I just had a huge catch-all catch clause to my main() and have it catch all `Exception` so that every exception gets handled?

`EDIT FOR CLARITY:` The question is more-or-less -- `Why does an unhandled exception that is not explicitly thrown in a method's signature, nor handled by a caller, not crash the JVM?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Why does an unhandled exception that is not explicitly thrown in a method's signature, nor handled by a caller, not crash the JVM?

Assuming this code is running in a Thread, the reason is, that unless you've set an `UnhandledExceptionHandler` on either the Thread class or the Thread instance, then the 'main' thread group is the default `UnhandledExceptionHandler`.  By default, the thread group handles unhandled exceptions by logging the stack trace to system.out, the thread 'dies' and the JVM does not crash.

You may want to consider implementing an UnhandledExceptionHandler that uses your email framework to notify you of these failures.

As other posters have suggested, the code should clean up resources like Channels and Session in a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

use a finally block to ensure the connection is closed.

```
public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        if (true)
        throw new NullPointerException("Test unexpected exception NPE");
    } finally {
        LOG.info("Closing SFTP connection");
        getSftpChannel().exit();
        getSession().disconnect();
        LOG.debug("SFTP Connection closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear -- the NPE in the example is just for testing purposes... the code obviously does not just have new NPE's being thrown for no reason ;-P -- so it does not make sense to put the entire codebase in a try/finally block

Comment: put the call to closeConnection in a finally block then.

Comment: the problem is if *any* unhandled exception is thrown *anywhere* in the codebase, I get this hung JVM. Not just in this example method, and not just with the example NPE.

Comment: The question is more of less -- `Why does an unhandled exception that is not explicitly thrown in a method's signature, nor handled by a caller, not crash the JVM?`

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: because a thrown exception from the main() is supposed to crash the jvm according to the spec. So if an exception is thrown someplace in the code, and is not handled locally, it should be passed up the stack until it either gets handled, or is thrown from main().